# What's the difference between 〜に対しての and 〜に対する?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

The question [understanding 対する](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4730/understanding-%E5%AF%BE%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B) details `[noun]に対する[noun]`, but what is the difference between `[noun]に対しての[noun]` and `[noun]に対する[noun]`?

[Space ALC](http://alc.co.jp) has a fair number of examples for both [`に対する`](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%81%AB%E5%AF%BE%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B) and [`に対しての`](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%81%AB%E5%AF%BE%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%AE) (though many more for `に対する` than `に対しての`).

The `日本語文型辞典` defines `に対する` as:

> 「それに対しての」「それに関しての」…「その問に対しての解答」のように、「NにたいしてのN」という形が用いられることもある。

and `〜に対して` as `「そのものごとに向けて／応じて」…` with one of the examples being:

> 現在容疑者に対しての取り調べが行われているところです。
>   "Presently there investigations being performed in regards with the suspect(s)."

Would `容疑者に対しての取り調べ` and `容疑者に対する取り調べ` have the same meaning in that sentence?

Are the two are always interchangeable, or are there some situations where one is more appropriate/natural than the other?

Comment: In my opinion. Aに対してのB => A same level of importance in the discussion as B. Aに対するB => A is less important than B in the discussion.

Answer (score 3):

The PDF at http://repository.tufs.ac.jp/bitstream/10108/20017/1/jlc033002.pdf says of 山田敏弘（２００２）「格助詞および複合格助詞の連体用法について」『岐阜大学国語文学』２９、岐阜大学国語文学会 on page 25:

> 「に対する」と「に対しての」のような「２つ以上の連体形を持つ場合、微細な違いを除き、ほぼ用法に差はない」（p.42）と結論している。

And says that, while the differences between the two weren't examined in detail in that report, it can be thought there are hardly any differences which stand out between the two in meaning.

(It then goes on to compare the frequency of the two using Google counts and from that says that に対する is more frequent than に対しての, but [Google counts may not be as reliable as you imagine](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/522/google-counts-may-not-be-as-reliable-as-you-imagine) so I'd take that with a grain of salt).

So I'd say, for most practical purposes, the two are interchangeable.