# What is the difference between に関しての and に関する?

Tags: word-choice, nuances

In [this](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q13151805898) question which I will paste below, the asker uses both, one right after the other.

> GTA5に関しての質問です。
>   GTA5に関する動画で、(...)

What is the difference between the two?

Comment: I think they are same. no difference.

Comment: @YuuichiTam Would you have a guess why the example question used two different ways? Just to avoid sounding repetitive maybe?

Comment: Yes,  I guess the asker just disfavored the repetitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is practically no difference in usage.

See also: [What's the difference between 〜に対しての and 〜に対する?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11515/whats-the-difference-between-%e3%81%ab%e5%af%be%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6%e3%81%ae-and-%e3%81%ab%e5%af%be%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b)